# REG QUERY get UninstallString for specific DisplayName

Tags: cmd, registry

1. using `REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f "myApp"` I determine myApp's guid.
2. then using `REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /v UninstallString` I get all uninstall strings
3. I have to find appropriate uninstall string by guid from step 1

How can I retrieve desired uninstall string in a single REG QUERY command?

I can not use power shell, have to manage in cmd.

Comment: I'm creating wix-less installer to replace current and must be able to uninstall app that was installed with the old one. So I don't know the guid. More of that, there is 'install wizard' as standalone app in programs and features that can be present multipletimes. I need to get rid of all of those as well. My question was not precise, I need to get the guid in a single cmd commnad not single query. With your help I'm gonna manage. Pls post your comment as answer, It's useful and correct.

Answer (score 2):

A single command line for usage directly in a command prompt window or another program running the Windows Command Processor `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with at least option `/C` would be:

```
@for /F "tokens=* delims=" %I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f "myApp" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') do @for /F "tokens=2*" %J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "%I" /v "UninstallString" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "UninstallString"') do @echo %K
```

This command line must be executed on 64-bit Windows with 64-bit `cmd.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. There is executed otherwise by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe` resulting in not finding registry key `WOW6432Node` because of [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

`cmd.exe` starts one more Windows Command Processor in background with the following command line on Windows installed in `C:\Windows`:

```
%ComSpec% /c C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f "myApp" 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
```

**REG** searches case-insensitive under the specified key and all its subkeys for the string `MyApp` and outputs the registry key and the registry value containing this string on being found out all.

The error message output by **REG** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) on not finding `MyApp` at all is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` to the device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and also `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The useful output of **REG** on `MyApp` found is redirected to handle **STDIN** (standard input) of command **FIND** which searches case-sensitive for the string `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and outputs the line containing this string to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of `cmd.exe` started in background. The string value itself containing `MyApp` is of no interest which is the reason for using **FIND** to filter the output of **REG**.

`cmd.exe` processing the **FOR** command captures everything output to **STDOUT** of in background started `cmd.exe` and processing it line by line. There would be by default split up each non-empty line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. If the first substring does not begin with a semicolon (default end of line character), the first space/tab delimited string would be assigned to the specified loop variable and otherwise the line would be ignored for further processing by **FOR**. That behavior is not wanted here because of the registry key contains definitely a space character. `tokens=* delims=` disables the line splitting behavior by the definition of an empty list of string delimiters. `tokens=*` would not be really necessary, but makes the processing of the captured line(s) a very little bit faster.

The entire registry key with a string value containing `MyApp` is assigned to the loop variable `I`. That string is used to run one more **FOR /F** to run in background again one more **CMD** to run **REG** to get output the string of the registry string value `UninstallString` with the registry key containing it which is already known. **FIND** is used again as filter to get just output the line containing case-insensitive `UninstallString` for further processing.

**REG** of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows output separated by spaces the string value name `UninstallString`, the value type being most likely `REG_SZ` (could be also `REG_EXPAND_SZ`) and the string which usually contains also one or more spaces. The **FOR /F** option `tokens=2*` is used this time to get assigned to the specified loop variable `J` the value type not further processed and the entire string value with the spaces to the next loop variable which is `K` according to the ASCII table.

`@echo %K` can be replaced by just `@%K` to execute the uninstall command instead of just writing it to **STDOUT** of `cmd.exe` processing the entire command line.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`